# failed to create custom database table on wordpress plugin activation via php OOP method

Tags: plugins

I am trying to create some custom database table on wordpress plugin activation with php OOP concept. But no database is created after plugin activation. Here is my code

```
class wpe_Main {
    public function __construct() {
        register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array($this,'create_wpe_enquiry_table'));
    }

    public function create_wpe_enquiry_table(){
        global $wpdb;
        $sql_enquiry = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$wpdb->prefix}wpe_enquiry (
        `id` int(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `enquiry_type_id` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
        `contact_email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        `contact_number` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        `contact_messenger` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        `query_title` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        `query_content` text NOT NULL,
        `attachment1` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        `attachment2` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        `attachment3` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        `user_ip` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        `query_cdate`  DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        `query_udate` DATETIME ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        `status` varchar(2) NOT NULL
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";

        $sql_enquiry_reply = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$wpdb->prefix}wpe_query_reply (
        `id` int(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        `quiry_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `reply_content` text NOT NULL,
        `user_ip` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        `reply_cdate`  DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        `reply_udate` DATETIME ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        `status` varchar(2) NOT NULL
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";

        $sql_enquiry_type = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$wpdb->prefix}wpe_query_part (
        `id` int(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        `part_value` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `part_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        `user_ip` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        `reply_cdate`  DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql_enquiry );
    dbDelta( $sql_enquiry_reply );
    dbDelta( $sql_enquiry_type );
}
}
$wpuf = new wpe_Main();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your class `wpe_Main` file is the mail file of the plugin?

Because `__FILE__` should return main plugin file path. So if your `wpe_Main` class is in a sub directory then the register activation won't work.

If you want you can try like below to avoid `__FILE__` confusion

Plugin path: `wp-content/plugin/sampleplugin/sample.php`

Then the hook should be like below

```
register_activation_hook( 'sampleplugin/sample.php', 
array($this,'create_wpe_enquiry_table'));
```

**Updated** after comments

If Your class in main plugin file then **for sure** the function is executing on plugin activation. Your table are not creating might be SQL error or typos. So please check the function responsible for creating table.

For simple testing on activation function try the below code

```
update_option('activation_test','its working');
```

then check the options, you can see that it should been updated or you can even send mail to test.

Testing the activation function is your conviniens. At the end `register_activation_hook` **will work on OOPS without any problem**. Check [Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook#Examples)

Comment: wpe_Main class is in main path of the plugins. After removing OOP class this code is ok but problem creates under the OOP class concept.

Comment: then it is working for sure. check my updated answer

Comment: Problem was on database query. Now it is solved. Thanks

Comment: Super. This is what I suggested. Thumbs up

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the real powers of `dbDelta()` here, when you use the `IF NOT EXISTS` clause.

### With the `IF NOT EXISTS` clause

When you use the `IF NOT EXISTS` check in:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
```

then `dbDelta()` will do the following matches:

```
if ( preg_match( "|CREATE TABLE ([^ ]*)|", $qry, $matches ) ) {
    $cqueries[ trim( $matches[1], '`' ) ] = $qry;
```

Here `$matches` is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => CREATE TABLE IF
    [1] => IF
)
```

and

```
trim( $matches[1], '`' )
```

gives the table name `IF`.

Then it will try to find it's fields with:

```
$tablefields = $wpdb->get_results("DESCRIBE {$table};");
```

or `DESCRIBE IF` that will (hopefully) not give any results. Thus `dbDelta()` will only try to run the raw creation query but skip any possible future updates to the table structure.

### Without the `IF NOT EXISTS` clause

If you remove the `IF NOT EXISTS` part, then the first runtime, for e.g. the `wp_wpe_query_part` table, will be

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wp_wpe_query_part (
        `id` int(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        `part_value` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `part_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        `user_ip` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        `reply_cdate`  DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and for the second runtime, when the table already exists, we will get these queries:

```
DESCRIBE wp_wpe_query_part;

SHOW INDEX FROM wp_wpe_query_part;

ALTER TABLE wp_wpe_query_partCHANGE COLUMN id `id` int(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;

ALTER TABLE wp_wpe_query_partCHANGE COLUMN part_value `part_value` int(11) NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE wp_wpe_query_partCHANGE COLUMN part_name `part_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE wp_wpe_query_partCHANGE COLUMN user_ip `user_ip` varchar(50) NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE wp_wpe_query_partCHANGE COLUMN reply_cdate `reply_cdate`  DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

If we later make some changes to the table structure, it will then modify the current table accordingly.